# Download all user aliases to a Google spreadsheet

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-admin-sdk

I am attempting to list all user aliases in our network. However, I am having a bit of trouble. I'm working from a bit of canned code here. I know the alias is an array but accessing it per user then listing just the aliases has me seeing double. Any help or tips is much appreciated!

```
  function AliasDomainUsersList() {

  var users_alias = [];
  var options_alias = {
    domain: "northstarmoving.com",     // Google Apps domain name
    customer: "my_customer",
    maxResults: 100,
    projection: "full",      // Fetch basic details of users
    viewType: "domain_public",
    orderBy: "email"          // Sort results by users
  }

  do {
    var response = AdminDirectory.Users.list(options_alias);
    response.users.forEach(function(user) {
      users_alias.push([user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail]);
    });

    // For domains with many users, the results are paged
    if (response.nextPageToken) {
      options_alias.pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
    }
  } while (response.nextPageToken);

  // Insert data in a spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Users-Aliases") || ss.insertSheet("Users-Aliases", 1);
  sheet.getRange(1,1,users_alias.length, users_alias[0].length).setValues(users_alias);

}
```

Comment: Are you getting error? What's the problem?

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out how to access and add all the user aliases. Right now, this code will write all the users to a Google Sheet which is great. However, I am trying to write all the user aliases to a separate sheet and that is the part where I am having trouble. Just the basics like accessing the elements of the alias array are not working for me.

Comment: Okay.  Then disregard my current answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work out the solution (with some help). Here it is:

```
  function getDomainUsersList() {

  var users = [];
  var options = {
    domain: "northstarmoving.com", // Google Apps domain name
    customer: "my_customer",
    maxResults: 500,
    projection: "full",      // Fetch details of users
    viewType: "domain_public",
    orderBy: "email"          // Sort results by users
  }

  do {
    var response = AdminDirectory.Users.list(options);
    response.users.forEach(function(user) {
      users.push([user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail]);
    });

    // For domains with many users, the results are paged
    if (response.nextPageToken) {
      options.pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
    }
  } while (response.nextPageToken);

  // Insert data in a spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Users") || ss.insertSheet("Users", 1);
  sheet.getRange(1,1,users.length, users[0].length).setValues(users);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might work.  I haven't tested this because I'm the only person in my business account.

```
function AliasDomainUsersList() {
  var users_alias = [];
  var options_alias = {
    domain: "northstarmoving.com",     // Google Apps domain name
    customer: "my_customer",
    maxResults: 100,
    projection: "full",      // Fetch basic details of users
    viewType: "domain_public",
    orderBy: "email"          // Sort results by users
  }

  do {
    var response = AdminDirectory.Users.list(options_alias);
    for(var i=0;i<response.users.length;i++) {//you will probably want to do this your way. 
      users_alias.push([response.users[i].name,response.users[i].primaryEmail]);
    }
    // For domains with many users, the results are paged
    if (response.nextPageToken) {
      options_alias.pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
    }
  } while (response.nextPageToken);

  // Insert data in a spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Users-Aliases") || ss.insertSheet("Users-Aliases", 1);
  sheet.getRange(1,1,users_alias.length, users_alias[0].length).setValues(users_alias);
  var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('AnotherSheet')
  var rg2=sheet2.getRange(1,1,users_alias.length,1);
  var vA2=rg2.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA2.length;i++) {
    vA2[i][0]=users_alias[i][1];
  }
  rg2.setValues(vA2);
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, thanks again for your help. Unfortunately, this output includes both alias and non-alias users.

Comment: Managed to work out the solution (with some help). Here it is: